# ¿Como soluciono el error com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.JniException?

Tags: java, java-8

estoy creando un sistema de trabajadores, en el cual se registran e ingresan su huella para marcar la hora de entrada y salida, pero tengo un error el cual me lanza:
"com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.JniException" Busqué en internet y sobre el error y me encontré que se resolvía actualizando los driver de Digitalperson SDK, lo hice pero el problema persiste.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al cerrar el jframe Registrar huella en la [X] que tiene un Dispose() y volver a abrirlo con el botón "Ingresar huella" del jDesktop formulario, me lanza el error:

El jframe de huella lo genero en el botón:

```
  private void btnHuellaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    huella ventanaHuella;
    ventanaHuella = new huella();
    ventanaHuella.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pude notar que el error se genera en Start(), en el lector.startcapture()

```
public class huella extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//identificar dispositivo
private DPFPCapture Lector = DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();
//Nos sirve para leer a modo de enrrolar, y crear una plantilla nueva, a base de 4 huellas.
private DPFPEnrollment Reclutador = DPFPGlobal.getEnrollmentFactory().createEnrollment();
//Nos sirve para leer a modo de verificar o comparar, a base de una plantilla creada anteriormente
private DPFPVerification Verificador = DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();
//La plantilla, nueva o rescatada
private DPFPTemplate template;
//A modo de CONSTANTE para crear plantillas
public String TEMPLATE_PROPERTY = "template";
//Para leer la huella, y definirla como un enrrolamiento
public DPFPFeatureSet featureSetInscripcion;
//Para leer la huella, y definirla como una verificación
public DPFPFeatureSet featureSetVerificacion;

public huella() {
    try {
        initComponents();
        Iniciar();
        start(); //Esta funcion tira error
        EstadoHuellas();
        btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
        btnIdentificar.setEnabled(false);
        btnVerificar.setEnabled(false);
        btnSalir.grabFocus();
        txtHuella.setEditable(false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e.getMessage(), "Error Desconocido", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("El error en el constructor es: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

protected void Iniciar() {...}

public void EnviarTexto(String mensaje) {...}

//

public void start() throws Exception {
    
    try {
        Lector.startCapture();
        System.out.println("Lector Abierto");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e.getMessage(), "Error Desconocido", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("El error en el metodo Start() es :" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

EDIT:
EL ERROR STACKTRACER:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.JniException
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture._impl.DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl$CaptureImpl.startCapture(DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl.java:187)
    at lacteosmalleco.huella.start(huella.java:127)
    at lacteosmalleco.huella.<init>(huella.java:47)
    at lacteosmalleco.Trabajador.btnHuellaActionPerformed(Trabajador.java:345)
    at lacteosmalleco.Trabajador.access$600(Trabajador.java:26)
    at lacteosmalleco.Trabajador$7.actionPerformed(Trabajador.java:162)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.JniException
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Acquisition.subscribe(Native Method)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture._impl.DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl$CaptureImpl.startCapture(DPFPCaptureFactoryImpl.java:185)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues a la pregunta el stack trace del error

Comment: Ahí agregué el error @BenjamínGuzmán

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se si lo resolviste pero tuve le mismo problema y lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

El error se debía ala variable Lector y el estado de la ventana [Stage], cuando abría la ventana y la cerraba el stage no cambiaba, por eso se producía el error, por lo tanto implemente un botón de salir, que al presionarlo lector pase a nulo y parara la captura con el método `stopcapture()`, te dejo el ejemplo de mi botón de salida:

```
@FXML
    public void salirSistema(ActionEvent e) {

        // debemos poner la variable lector en parar captura y nula
        enrolarLector.stopCapture();
        enrolarLector = null;
        Node source = (Node) e.getSource();     //Me devuelve el elemento al que hice click
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();    //Me devuelve la ventana donde se encuentra el elemento
        stage.close();  //Me cierra la ventana
    }
```